# Is there a way to name a Rust doctest?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Doctests [commandeer the language identifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html#attributes) to allow you to add "attributes" that affect the behavior of the test.

However, there doesn't appear to be a way to add a name to a documentation test. Is there a way I can better identify them when looking at a long output from a test run?

I'd love to have something like

````
/// ```[construction_test]
/// # use my_crate::MyStruct;
/// MyStruct{ name: "jk".to_owned() };
/// ```
struct MyStruct{
    name: String,
}
````

that would result in the usual named output:

```
-> cargo test --doc

    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 7.71s
   Doc-tests my_crate

running 1 test
test src/my_crate/lib.rs - my_crate::MyStruct::construction_test (line 10) ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.45s

   Doc-tests my_crate
```

Answer (score 1):

No. However, 11 days ago (as of time of writing) [an RFC for exactly that was submitted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3311). So we can wait and see if it is accepted.